# stack/jitter overlapping points using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I've got a continuous variable where most observations are concentrated at one end of the spectrum. I'd like to display this in a graphic somewhat like this:

[image: example I want to replicate]

I tried it with position_jitter:

```
ver_ocupacoes |> 
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = n, y = 0))+ 
geom_point(alpha = 0.5, position = position_jitter(width = 0, height = 10, seed = 1))
```

And obtained this:
[image: jitter_example]

Also tried making a geom_dotplot instead:

```
ver_ocupacoes |>
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = n))+
  geom_dotplot(stackdir = "center",
               stackratio = 0.5,
               dotsize = 0.2,
               method="dotdensity",
               stackgroups = T,
               binpositions="all")
```

And this was the result:

[image: dotplot example]

So neither one is quite what I want. Any ideas on how to jitter the points around a central axis like in the first example?

Comment: You should try to provide some data for us to play with. That said, you could try sina plot from ggforce (https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/geom_sina.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `geom_dotplot`, you can use `position_jitter` with `height = 0` and having the width approximately equal to the binwidth. Setting the binwidth to be a bit narrower will also help from the look of things.

```r
ver_ocupacoes |>
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = n))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_dotplot(stackdir = "center",
               stackratio = 0.5,
               dotsize = 1,
               method ="dotdensity",
               stackgroups = TRUE,
               binpositions = "all",
               binwidth = 5000,
               position = position_jitter(width = 5000, height = 0),
               color = 'red4', fill = 'red') +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

Obviously, we don't have your data, but the following appears to be a reasonable approximation and was used in the above example:

```r
set.seed(1)
ver_ocupacoes <- data.frame(n = 1e5 * rexp(200, 2)^2.5/3)
```